# iOS Custom Lock Screen Alternative

Tags: ios, lockscreen, mdm

Let me first begin by explaining my goal for this app.  I am looking for ideas on the best way to accomplish my goal (or at least close to my goal).  This app is completely internal and thus does not need to comply with any apple guidelines (aka, can use private api's).

Our company has ~20 iOS devices.  These devices are used by multiple people throughout the organization.  Often times we are looking for a specific device and need to be able to track it down.  So I am looking for a way to track who has what device.

My initial thought was to make an app that allows the user to pick their name from the list and then have a server that keeps track of who has what device.  This worked well for a while, but now people have decided its too much work and have stopped using it.  Users can just not open the app or press the home button to exit it.  So now I'm looking for alternatives.

Here are some ideas that didn't work:

- Custom Lock Screen - (Requires jailbroken devices so not an option)
- "Lock To App" from Apple Configurator - (No way to exit our app.  We don't want to hinder normal use.  Note exit(0) will just cause iOS to restart our app)
- MDM options - (Didn't see any that would provide this functionality. Let me know if otherwise.  We would like to implement it ourselves, but a 3rd party is an option)

At this point I'm just looking for ideas or knowledge.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a sticker on each device and then, if i need a specific device, i would push a notification with a message like: "person with the device X ..we need it in room Y " .Then it's up to the person who has it to return it (or smth).

The sticker itself would be a numbered decal... or a picture..or something like that.

It's just an idea

Comment: Thanks for your answer skytz.  This is an option - one that we had considered actually.  We had a few concerns with this approach though.  First, this would require the user to be actually watching the phone for push notifications.  Often times people will be gone to lunch or in a meeting and won't be able to see the message.  The other issue was when people were in meetings and using the ipad's to project, we were hoping not to pop up push notifications on the big screen ;).